# How to match a string's content in Javascript code, which can either be inside single or double quotation marks?

Tags: regex

http://regex101.com/r/nT6oO6

This regex: `'([^']+?)\'.someMethod\(\)`

matches `'Hello World "xaxaxaxa" xx'.someMethod()`

I could easily make it match the contents of `"Hello World 'xaxaxaxa' xx".someMethod()` with a seperate regex, slightly modified. How to match the contents of those strings with a single regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(["'])(.+?)(?=\1\.someMethod\(\))
```

And use `matched group #2` i.e. `$2`

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sG6rZ8)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by merging the two `regexes` together:

```
(\'([^']+?)\'.someMethod\(\)|\"([^"]+?)\".someMethod\(\))
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/gX0tO5)